# Voice channel users have UserStatus.Offline although everyone is online

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm using Discord.Net and want to mute/unmute users in a voice channel. I'm not sure if

```
voiceChannelUser.ModifyAsync(guildUserProperties => guildUserProperties.Mute = true /* or false */)
```

throws exceptions if a user is not online and the bot tries to mute/unmute him. So when I join a voice channel and the bot fetches all the users from that voice channel

```
IEnumerable<IGuildUser> voiceChannelUsers = await voiceChannel.GetUsersAsync().FlattenAsync();
```

the collection returns a count of 1, as expected. Before running the mute/unmute task I don't know if it might be that a user has gone offline and the collection doesn't know about. So the `ModifyAsync` might throw an exception because the user is offline now?

The thing is that when checking my own status via

```
bool iAmOffline = voiceChannelUsers.First().Status == UserStatus.Offline; // expected false, actual true
```

it returns `true` although it should be `false` because I'm online. So

- is that check required to prevent exceptions?
- if yes, why does it say I'm offline although I'm not?

I'm using Discord.Net v2.3.

Comment: you seem to be not sure about a number of things. Why don't you debug the code and log any exceptions? This will point you in the right direction of what needs to be fixed

Comment: I debugged the code and saw that my status is offline, although I'm not. I would like to know why this happens

Comment: The user status doesn't have anything to do with muting the user. You most likely don't have the presence intent enabled in the discord developer portal

Comment: @Anu6is yes, enabling the presence intent did the trick. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66554743/7764329 I debugged it for offline users and it seems that I have to perform the check before to avoid exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this comment

[Voice channel users have UserStatus.Offline although everyone is online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66519113/voice-channel-users-have-userstatus-offline-although-everyone-is-online#comment117606575_66519113)

all I had to do is to enable the presence intent

[image]

So when unmuting a muted user I use the code like so

```
IGuildUser guildUser = null; // receive the user from somewhere
SocketGuildUser socketGuildUser = guildUser as SocketGuildUser;
bool userIsMuted = socketGuildUser.VoiceState?.IsMuted == true;
bool userNotOffline = socketGuildUser.Status != UserStatus.Offline;

if (userIsMuted && userNotOffline)
{
    await guildUser.ModifyAsync(guildUserProperties => guildUserProperties.Mute = false);
}
```

It seems that I have to perform the offline check, otherwise the `ModifyAsync` method throws exceptions for offline users.